# Cross error loss function cause division by zero error

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, loss-function, activation-function

How to calculate cross entropy when actual output is 0? Would not it give indf brcause of log(0) and the cross entropy for binary classification is given by:
-(ylog(actual_output)+(1-y)*(1-actual_output)

Comment: Hi there, Can you add some helper code, will help us in debugging easier, Also generally never you get a perfect 1, it's always like .9999

Comment: I am dealing with input number with value around 150 applying sigmoid to such value would give 1

Comment: What your goal is exactly?

Comment: I am building neural network for binary classification and input values always large in my case and that woud make sigmoid gives 1 and this will cause problem with cross entropy because of log(0) for the cross entropy and division on zero for it is derivation so what I want exctly is a way to make sure I do not get in this problems in cross entropy function

Comment: Did you normalise your inputs as nn doesn't work without it